# How to order a stacked barplot to have the biggest chunk at the bottom? Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-chart

I am trying to have my stacked barplot ordered with the largest piece at the bottom but I am not sure how to order it.

**Sample dataset**

```
dataset = {'Year': [2019,2019,2020,2020,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,
                   2020,2020,2020,2020],
           'Quantity': [100,50,25,30,40,50,200,600,20,40,100,20,50,400,250,300,125,75,90,10,225,550,450,55],
           'Regions': ['Europe','Asia','Africa','Africa','Other','Asia','Africa','Other','America','America','Europe','Europe',
                      'Other','Europe','Asia','Africa','Asia','Europe','Other','Africa','Europe','Asia','Africa','Europe']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

**Here is my code to create the graph:**

```
df_pt = df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Regions', values='Quantity')

df_pt.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6))
```

If you run the code you will see that the biggest part is not at the bottom.

**Output Graph:**
[image]

Comment: Based on your data I assume, each bar should be sorted individually? Is this correct?

Comment: @Mr.T I edited my question

Comment: Interesting, this is surprisingly more difficult than I thought it would be using just matplotlib and pandas plot.  This might worth a feature enhancement request, something like segment order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you are:

```
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_bar
import pandas as pd

dataset = {'Year': [2019,2019,2020,2020,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,
                   2020,2020,2020,2020],
           'Quantity': [100,50,25,30,40,50,200,600,20,40,100,20,50,400,250,300,125,75,90,10,225,550,450,55],
           'Regions': ['Europe','Asia','Africa','Africa','Other','Asia','Africa','Other','America','America','Europe','Europe',
                      'Other','Europe','Asia','Africa','Asia','Europe','Other','Africa','Europe','Asia','Africa','Europe']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Regions']).sum().reset_index()

p = ggplot(df) + aes(x='Year', y='Quantity', group='factor(Quantity)', fill='Regions') + geom_bar(stat='identity', alpha=0.8, show_legend=True)
print(p)
```

[image: Stacked bar plot]

Comment: Actually this solution doesn't really solve my problem. Your code plots each data point distinctively with the largest quantity at the bottom and smallest at the top. While I would like each region to be combined together and then sorted with the largest rectangle at the bottom.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "each data point distinctively"? The plot is a bar chart, so the data are aggregated, not distinct. The plotnine solution above produces a plot similar to the first one in your post, but with the largest rectangle at the bottom for each year, as requested (bear in mind that I modified one of your data set values).

Comment: Yes, it does sort the rectangles. But when I run it on the sample data I get several rectangles for 'Europe' or several for 'Asia' (for the same year), while I only wish to get one per region per year. (I added the graph with your code in my question for you to see, will delete later) Even the years look weird

Comment: What do you want to happen when you have several values for the same (Year, Region) combination? Sum them?

Comment: Yes I wish to sum them up to see the total Quantity per (Year, Region)

Comment: Then the poltnine solution will do exactly that. See the added plot.

Comment: It's the same output basically, it works with the data that you created but with the one I gave you (more than one region per year), the problem will still be the same.

Comment: In the plot above I has used the original data you posted, which has two rows for (Asia, 2020) and the plot is correctly aggregating them. You are using the plotnine solution, right? I am going to delete the matplotlib solution for clarity.

Comment: To be specific, you have (Asia, 2020, 50) twice in your data set so the bar for (Asia, 2020) should have a height of 100, and on the plot I posted you can see that the height of the (green) Asia bar for 2020 is indeed 100.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the sampled data to make sure I have several regions per year. By using the plotnine code I am getting the graph that I updated. I am not changing anything to your code.

Comment: I see where the problem comes from. I have updated the data set, the code and the plot. That should address the issue.

Comment: Thank you David. I should have realized that the graph didn't know it had to group the data... Anyways, I appreciate the time you took. I didn't know I could use an R-style solution so thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. One suggestion: when you have several rows for the same combination of columns ([Year, Region] in this case), you should either add an extra column to explain the reason for these different values (e.g. different months in the same year? different countries in the same region?) or at least provide the explanation as a comment, because otherwise these rows can appear as duplicates or errors.